# Duplicate content in event profile pages

Tags: google-search, duplicate-content

I have a website which has events. Events have description, dates and locations. Single event may be held in multiple locations on different dates, but the description is still the same.

How can I prevent "duplicate content" on such events or this case is OK for search engine optimization?

Comment: 1. Do you have dedicated page for each single event?
2. Do the event listing pages (those showing multiple events) have the full event description or short version of the original description?

Comment: 1. Yes I have a dedicated page for every event (on a different url). 2. The short description (shortened version of the long description) is shown on listings.

Comment: Great. Final Question: Do the listing pages (those showing multiple events) contain any additional information for any event that you don't have on the dedicated page for that event?

Comment: Nope, it's exactly the opposite. Listings have summarized information about events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your current setup:

1. You have dedicated page for every `event` with the details of that event.
2. Every event may have multiple `locations` / `dates` and for those `locations` / `dates` you have event listing pages.
3. The listing pages for `locations` / `dates` contain short description of the original events. Other than that they don't provide any additional unique information.

For this sort of structure, abide by the following two rules for better Search Engine Optimization (SEO):

1. Make sure each dedicated event page have `rel="canonical"` properly set to it's own URL. You'll find details on `canonical` [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en).
2. Since your event listing pages for `locations` & `dates` do not contain any additional unique information, there is no reason to index them for search engines. You may use `noindex` meta tag to prevent Search Engines from indexing them for search results. Search Engines will still find your events, but they'll simply show the dedicated event pages in the Search Result.

You'll find more information on `noindex` [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noindex).

This way Search Engines will index all your unique `event` information without any duplicates.